# Does the sum of 2 numbers in the list equal the desired sum?

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, array, decision-problem

## The Task

This is my first challenge so apologies if it is very simple!  In this challenge, your task is to write a program or function which takes in a list of integers and a desired sum and outputs a truthy or falsey value based on whether the list contains two numbers that can be summed together to achieve the desired sum.

## Input

The input must be acquired in a standard way for your language.  The list of integers can be any standard collection type for your language but cannot be a hashed set, sorted set, or any highly functional collection type.  Don't assume the input is sorted, any valid integer type is acceptable.

The desired sum is also an integer and must be provided to your program as input.

## Output

The output may be a function return, console log, writing to a file, etc...  Any valid Truthy or Falsey value is acceptable.

## Additional Rules

- The input list may or may not be sorted.
- Duplicate values may occur in the list
- The same item in the list may not be summed to itself to achieve the desired sum (Eg. [3,4,5] with desired sum 6 will expect False because 3 cannot be used twice)
- Standard loopholes are not allowed.

Test Cases

```
INPUT                 OUTPUT
[3,4,5], 6            Falsey
[1,2,3,4,5,6],11      Truthy
[4,23,8174,42,-1],41  Truthy
[1,1,1,1,1,3],3       Falsey
[2,1,1,1,53,2],4      Truthy
[2,2,2,2],4           Truthy
[3],3                 Falsey
[],-43                Falsey
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: at least two numbers or just two numbers?

Comment: @marmeladze Just 2 numbers.

Comment: Nice first challenge!

Comment: Can the sum integer be zero or negative?

Comment: Can we assume that the input least contains at least 2 elements?

Comment: @Arnauld No.  I should add those test cases.

Comment: Could we take in a length of the list and.or assume a certain sentinel value will not be in the input?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Any possible integer for desired sum and any possible integer within the list so no sentinel values.  Only two inputs, length is not provided.

Comment: @maple_shaft my language doesn't support a native list type, it can really only take in a null terminated string or a list of numbers with a sentinel,shouldn't this be the "native" list type?

Comment: Can we choose an empty output for falsey and `1` for truthy?

Comment: `[3],6` should also be Falsey, which one solution might currently accept as truthy.

Comment: I think the other challenge should be closed as a duplicate of this one instead. I like this one better.

Answer (score 9):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 3 bytes

```
⊇Ċ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/@oq/1Il/b//9GGOkY6xjomOqY6ZrH/DQ0B)

```
⊇Ċ+   input as STDIN, output as ARG1
      (prove that:)
⊇     the input is a superset of
 Ċ       a list of two elements
  +         which sums up to the output
```

Comment: @Fatalize For the love of God, I was having a dinner.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
ŒcS€ċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@390UnLwo6Y1R7r///8fbaJjZKxjYWhuomNipKNrGPvfxBAA)

-1 byte by using the Unordered Pairs atom

```
ŒcS€ċ  Main Link; left argument is the array, right argument is the required sum
  S€   Take the sum of each...
Œc     ...unordered pair...
    ċ  Check if the sum array contains the right argument
```

-1 byte thanks to Erik!

## 4 bytes

```
Œc§i
```

This does the same thing but with a newer language feature of vectorize-at-depth-1 sum. Thanks Dennis! :D Credit to [@Riolku](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90304/riolku) for noticing this.

Comment: You can use `ċ` instead of `⁹e` to outgolf MATL. The rules don't specify that the values must be consistent, only truthy/falsey.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Oh thanks :D Outgolfed MATL and 05AB1E :)

Comment: Umm, your TIO doesn't contain any code? ;) And you forgot to change the `6` to `<s>6</s> 5` based on your edit?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ehhh lol thanks, I failed at copy-pasting. And yes I forgot that, thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
æ2ùOIå
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@394mdHhnf6eh5f@/x9tomNkrGNhaG6iY2Kko2sYy2ViCAA)

**Explanation**

```
æ        # get powerset of first input
 2ù      # keep only those of size 2
   O     # sum each
    Iå   # check if 2nd input is in the list of sums
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>43</s> 42 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to mbomb007</sup>

```python
lambda a,b:any(b-a.pop()in a for x in a*1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#NYpBDoIwFAX3nOIvW/Iw@W1BQ@JJahcFITTR0hCMenDXKKiZzbyX6Y@n5eKvzdmTR1P7@BRN4XdpTEKGSJ76caIHrZqzXO5DuHTEdZpCnKkXeYjpNgspF6thUDpQlVmGwjZROTBn1kBpHHhvYBQKdjC8Vn@0g86s@q1SQ32K9djY/Js4FEa/4li0vh26Nw)

Comment: Why do you need `[:]`?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer because I'm using `a.pop()` and iterating over `a`, without it it will iterate over the popped list, resulting in only half runs. `a[:]` is there just to make the code run `len(a)` times.

Comment: Oh so that's how you make a copy of a list. What code-golf teaches you...

Comment: [Better TIO test suite](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#NYpNDoIwGAX3nOJbtubVpD@gIfEktYuCEJpg2xCMenDXKKiZzbyX6U/nZfTX5uLJo6l9fLJG@H1OmfEQyVOfJnrQqrZ2fLkPYexI1nkKcaae7ULMt5lxvlgNg9KBqsJKKGwTlYOUhTVQGkd5MDAKQjoYuVZ/tIMurPqtUkN9ivXY2PybOAijXzGJ1rdD9wY). Also, can you use `1*a` instead of `a[:]`?

Comment: @mbomb007 yep, now it has a perfect score :3

Comment: Is there a test case you could use that would give a different answer if you had `a` instead of `a*1`? Because right now, the results are the same.

Comment: @mbomb007 `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],1` or any case where the right numbers are in the first half if the list

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 29 bytes

```
!FreeQ[Tr/@#~Subsets~{2},#2]&
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
2XN!sm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#NYq7DYAwFAN7b0HvFO@TwADUVBRI0ZNYgIr9FSCArvFZtzfdluE82ry2anTmQEEVKruxBERQnWqcZHS6MknA5al@LGCo@lk26l08R6fvNwkktws)

#### Explanation

```
2XN   % Implicitly input an array. Combinations of elements taken 2 at a time
      % The result is a matrix where each row is a combination
!s    % Sum of each row
m     % Implicitly input a number. Ismember function. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>38</s> 43 bytes

```js
a=>n=>[...a].some(_=>a.includes(n-a.pop()))
```

---

### Try It

```js
f=
a=>n=>[...a].some(_=>a.includes(n-a.pop()))
o.innerText=`           f([3,4,5])(6) = ${f([3,4,5])(6)}
    f([1,2,3,4,5,6])(11) = ${f([1,2,3,4,5,6])(11)}
f([4,23,8174,42,-1])(41) = ${f([4,23,8174,42,-1])(41)}
     f([1,1,1,1,1,3])(3) = ${f([1,1,1,1,1,3])(3)}
    f([2,1,1,1,53,2])(4) = ${f([2,1,1,1,53,2])(4)}
         f([2,2,2,2])(4) = ${f([2,2,2,2])(4)}
               f([3])(3) = ${f([3])(3)}
              f([])(-43) = ${f([])(-43)}
     f([1,2,3,4,5,6])(3) = ${f([1,2,3,4,5,6])(3)}`
```

```css
pre{font-size:14px;line-height:1.75}
```

```html
<pre id=o>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `f([1,2,3,4,5,6])(3)`. Try using `[...a].some` instead?

Comment: Out of interest I tried porting Rod's Python answer, it also came out at 43 bytes.

Comment: @Neil, I was trying to figure out a shorter way, without using `includes()` but I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>39 37</s> 36 bytes

```hs
(a:t)#n=n`elem`map(a+)t||t#n
_#n=1<0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#NYpBCsIwEEX3niIwmxa/4CRpFbFH8AQh2Cy6KJihlCx79zgE5a/ee7926VF6kknm5bPkOaetS@e@HEchOb018PNac1rFTEbjy2z7KsWE4OAxRBphAsOiIcZIzGo8rMOdbx7e4sKRPLfffy6SU2F/ODhY/TTTphDrFw) Example usage: `[1,3,2,5] # 3`. Returns `True` or `False`.

---

**Alternative** (also 36 bytes)

```hs
f(a:t)=map(a+)t++f t
f e=e
(.f).elem
```

Comment: I felt like using applicatives that you can get this in only 31 bytes but it fails a couple test cases for some reason: `g x d=any(\x->x==d)$(+)<$>x<*>x`

Comment: @maple_shaft Interesting idea, but it computes for each list element also the sum with itself, that's way some test cases fail. By the way it can be shortened to 22 bytes: `x#d=elem d$(+)<$>x<*>x`

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>114</s> 113 bytes

```
i,j,k="F";main(c,v)char**v;{for(--c;++i<c;)for(j=0;++j<c;)k=j^i&atoi(v[i])+atoi(v[j])==atoi(v[c])?"T":k;puts(k);}
```

Here's the output

```
C:\eng\golf>a.exe 3 4 5 6
F
C:\eng\golf>a.exe 1 2 3 4 5 6 11
T
C:\eng\golf>a.exe 4 23 8174 42 -1 41
T
C:\eng\golf>a.exe 1 1 1 1 1 3
F
C:\eng\golf>a.exe 2 1 1 1 53 2 4
T
C:\eng\golf>a.exe 2 2 2 2 4
T
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>59</s> <s>53</s> 37 bytes

[inspiration comes from this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120806/46172)

```
->a,b{a.map{|e|a.include?(b-e)}.any?}
```

will now look where can I chop a few bytes -))

**HISTORY**

```
#53 bytes
->a,b{a.combination(2).map{|e|e.reduce(&:+)==b}.any?}

#59 bytes 
->a,b{a.combination(2).map{|e|e.reduce(&:+)}.any?{|x|x==b}}
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP (>= 7.1), <s>53</s> <s>51</s> <s>50</s> 46 Bytes

```
<?foreach($_GET[0]as$c)+$$c||${$_GET[1]-$c}=a;
```

sadly it's quite big but at least better than 2 loops. `+a` fails with a warning if the sum can be made => non empty output => *truthy*. Outputs nothing if the sum can not be made => *falsey*.

Thanks @user63956 !

Comment: You forget the `<?` and if the terminate in true cases should be printable the shortest status i Know is `!0`

Comment: @JörgHülsermann `<?` for `$_GET`? Fair enough. Why should I print something if I can use exit code golfing? If I wanted to print something `die(a)` would also work just fine.

Comment: Can you explain me how you will get the exit code when it not is printed with using the $_GET array as input? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/537bbdd8b7f8a06f573b88d37b7b81327f673b0b

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Using CGI

Comment: Thank You I have never tried CGI and $_GET together before. I am sad that I could only one upvote

Comment: You can save a few bytes with variable variables instead of `$q`: `$$c` and `${$_GET[1]-$c}`.

Answer (score 2):

## [TAESGL](https://github.com/tomdevs/taesgl), 8 bytes

```
Ş⇒AĨB-AĖ
```

[**Interpreter**](https://tomdevs.github.io/TAESGL/v/1.2.0/index.html?code=XHUwMTVlXHUyMWQyQVx1MDEyOEItQVx1MDExNg==&input=WzQsMjMsODE3NCw0MiwtMV0sNDE=)

**Explanation**

```
Ş⇒        Array.some with anonymous function on implicit input
  AĨ      first input includes
    B-    second input minus
      AĖ  first input popped
```

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 53 bytes

```
#(loop[[v & r]%](if v(or((set r)(- %2 v))(recur r))))
```

Uses destructuring to take the first and rest of the input list (and subsequent `recur` of rest), and returns the number "target - value1" if found in the set of remaining numbers (a "truthy"), nil otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, 138 bytes

```
boolean c(int[]a,int s){String r="";for(int l=a.length,i=0,j;i<l;i++)for(j=-1;++j<l;)if(i!=j)r+=(a[i]+a[j])+",";return r.contains(s+",");}
```

**Explanation:**

```
boolean c(int[]a,int s){             // Method with integer-array and integer parameters and boolean return-type
  String r="";                       // Temp String
  for(int l=a.length,i=0,j;i<l;i++)  //  Loop (1) over the input array
    for(j=-1;++j<l;)                 //   Inner loop (2) over the input array again
      if(i!=j)                       //    If the index of both loops aren't equal (so not the same item in the list)
        r+=(a[i]+a[j])+",";          //     Append the sum with a comma to the temp-String
                                     //   End of loop (2) (implicit / single-line body)
                                     //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  return r.contains(s+",");          //  Return whether the temp-String contains the given sum (+ comma)
}                                    // End of method
```

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#jZBBbsMgEEX3OcXUKxATq9hOWolyhK6ytLwgrpNgEYgAt6oszp7aTrutrL9AmvmP@TOtUSHA@7gBCFFF3cL96JzplIWWaBvrRuH0QKDjIXptz@BllomT83MXjFS56ew5XlDLZ@yFfjNCM0ZnQy@3XDDWTyWqT0Q/yZ56JomqdcNU3TeUZZgJ38XBW/B562xU2gYS5joV6Q5wG45mCvWb7dPpD7hOHvIIUzeg6Jwd4PAdYnfN3RDz29SKxpKW2O4LliVGjgWWWOEO9wk5p1SsoSosSnzlLxVWBW55wmotWSBftCuxmLDV1KL/gXVfcfxTmbBcOX@5UML9w5426f4D)

```
class M{
  static boolean c(int[]a,int s){String r="";for(int l=a.length,i=0,j;i<l;i++)for(j=-1;++j<l;)if(i!=j)r+=(a[i]+a[j])+",";return r.contains(s+",");}
  
  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6},11));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{4,23,8174,42,-1},41));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{2,1,1,1,53,2},4));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{2,2,2,2},4));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{1,1,1,1,1,3},3));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{3,4,5},6));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
true
true

false
false
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 38 bytes

```
MemberQ[Total/@#~Permutations~{2},#2]&
```

input style [{1,2,3,4,5,6},11]

Comment: `#` is short for `#1`, and infix notations can shave a byte: `MemberQ[Total/@#~Permutations~{2},#2]&`

Comment: @JungHwan thanks. I'm new to this. Where is your answer?

Answer (score 1):

## R, 32 bytes

```
function(x,l)x%in%combn(l,2,sum)
```

Returns an anonymous function. `combn` returns all combinations of `l` taken `m` at a time, in this case 2, and then optionally applies a function, in this case `sum`. Returns an empty logical vector `logical(0)` for an empty first input, which I define for this problem as falsey, and `TRUE` or `FALSE` corresponding to the other elements otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#S7P9n1aal1ySmZ@nUaGTo1mhmpmnmpyfm5SnkaNjpFNcmqv5P03DSCdZwxDINdYx0THV1PwPAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 41 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,*c:a-b in c or c and f(a,*c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#NY5LCsMwDET3PYWWdpks/ElbAj2J8EJOMARat4Te35WbFAnBvHkLtXJ/yDMvQoKM8zzJkGmtNNNr0yN1oWJEC9uKEpV6y8wBEWMCXRKYHTx@ABqd6yjCB9zcNSJ6DIqi283/hNSX2R95DPBqpTSd6L2t9WOK0Y/E2vYF)
Recursive aproach with *flexible* input and output. Returns an empty set as falsy.

Comment: This doesn't work for test case `[], -43`. [Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#NYzNCsIwEITP5in2mMj0kJ9WKfRJQg7bPwzUWErVx69pVQaGndmP2cZm4nvbMzFanLuai5Zioo4eSzZOPY2S80Nt71ucBtK1OGW0GV48yZjm5yqVEqd5iWmVo8wbrNTmLRzKAKqE1zA4IqoArYV3MBZXfXFwBoUOcHqn/rIBVnjzS6WFycReHDruLxJQOPsB)

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 28 bytes

```matlab
@(a,b)any(pdist(a,@plus)==b)
```

This defines an anonymous function with inputs `a`: column vector (possibly empty); `b`: number.

The code also works in Octave except if the first input is empty, which causes an error. **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#RYrLCsIwEEX3fkWXCaSBebQKl0D/o3TRIgVBpFBd@PVxDLFyN3POnDXFGPPg5rD4@fF22/W2P42G7f7afUqLz6sbBYpuakLvT0YERjHop9AQFalgwYXOCmW0ZA@lWv8mJqU4rqYT8Lessuzgf25Hq@LzBw)**

#### Explanation

`pdist(a,@fun)` applies function `fun` (in our case, addition) to each combination of two rows of the input matrix `a` (in our case, a column vector). The output is a column vector. `any(...==b)` gives true if any of the results equals the input number `b`.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 9 bytes

```
/msd.cE2E
```

[Try it](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Fmsd.cE2E&input=%5B3%2C4%2C5%5D6%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Falsey%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%5D%2C11%20%20%20%20%20%20Truthy%0A%5B4%2C23%2C8174%2C42%2C-1%5D%2C41%20%20Truthy%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C3%5D%2C3%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Falsey%0A%5B2%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C53%2C2%5D%2C4%20%20%20%20%20%20Truthy%0A%5B2%2C2%2C2%2C2%5D%2C4%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Truthy%0A%5B3%5D%2C3%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Falsey%0A%5B%5D%2C-43%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Falsey&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B3%2C4%2C5%5D%0A6%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%5D%0A11%0A%5B4%2C23%2C8174%2C42%2C-1%5D%0A41%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C3%5D%0A3%0A%5B2%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C53%2C2%5D%0A4%0A%5B2%2C2%2C2%2C2%5D%0A4%0A%5B3%5D%0A3%0A%5B%5D%0A-43&debug=0&input_size=2)

```
/msd.cE2E
    .cE2     # All subsets of length 2
 msd         # The sum of each subset
/       E    # Number of occurrences of the input number
```

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, <s>90</s> 92 bytes

```
f(a,k)==(for i in 1..#a-1 repeat for j in i+1..#a repeat(q:=a.i+a.j;q=k=>return true);false)
```

test

```
(42) -> f([3,4,5],6)
   (42)  false
                                                            Type: Boolean
(43) -> f([1,2,3,4,5,6],11)
   (43)  true
                                                            Type: Boolean
(44) -> f([4,23,8174,42,-1],11)
   (44)  false
                                                            Type: Boolean
(45) -> f([4,23,8174,42,-1],41)
   (45)  true
                                                            Type: Boolean
(46) -> f([2,23,8174,42,2],2)
   (46)  false
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 71 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
lambda L,n:n in map(sum,list(combinations(L,2)))
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#NYpNDoIwGAX3PUWXLXks@gMaEm/ADbCLqhC/hLYESjw@Cmpm8@Zlhst1G324PTxvEZvIKfLgJ7GsASMtWdxTuFH0mVJcRAstpWTDnAKn3M85pXHhFKY052J7PWnsuWqmmWLmgygoTmsWUm6dgUXlwGvWKWgcitpBKdZZaIOzOllYjVI5WLVXf4yDYZ3@WWWgP8V@HBz7mziU1rwB)

Yes, I know there is already a better solution posted.

Answer (score 0):

### C#, <s>96</s> 90 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;a=>n=>Enumerable.Range(0,a.Count).Any(i=>a.Skip(i+1).Any(j=>a[i]+j==n));
```

Compiles to a `Func<List<int>, Func<int, bool>>`. Formatted version:

```c#
Func<List<int>, Func<int, bool>> f = a => n =>
    Enumerable.Range(0, a.Count).Any(i => a.Skip(i + 1).Any(j => a[i] + j == n));
```

Old `for` loop version for 96 bytes:

```c#
a=>n=>{for(int i=0,j,l=a.Count;i<l;++i)for(j=i+1;j<l;)if(a[i]+a[j++]==n)return 1>0;return 1<0;};
```

Answer (score 0):

### [C#](http://csharppad.com/gist/e11a62dffa6ce06e38335c5da1f8ac52), <s>103</s> 102 bytes

---

#### Data

- **Input** `Int32[]` `l` A list of `Int32` to sum
- **Input** `Int32` `r` The result to check against
- **Output** `Boolean` A result indicating if the sum can be performed

---

#### Golfed

```cs
(int[] l,int r)=>{for(int x=l.Length,y;--x>=0;)for(y=0;y<x;)if(l[x]+l[y++]==r)return 1>0;return 0>1;};
```

---

#### Ungolfed

```cs
( int[] l, int r ) => {
   for( int x = l.Length, y; --x >= 0; )
      for( y = 0; y < x; )
         if( l[ x ] + l[ y++ ] == r )
            return 1 > 0;
   
   return 0 > 1;
};
```

---

#### Ungolfed readable

*`Working on it...`*

---

#### Full code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Namespace {
   class Program {
      static void Main( String[] args ) {
        Func<Int32[], Int32, Boolean> f = ( int[] l, int r ) => {
            for( int x = l.Length, y; --x >= 0; )
                for( y = 0; y < x; )
                    if( l[ x ] + l[ y++ ] == r )
                        return 1 > 0;
   
            return 0 > 1;
        };

        List<KeyValuePair<Int32[], Int32>>
            testCases = new List<KeyValuePair<Int32[], Int32>>() {
                new KeyValuePair<Int32[], Int32>( new Int32[] { 3, 4, 5 }, 6 ),
                new KeyValuePair<Int32[], Int32>( new Int32[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, 11 ),
                new KeyValuePair<Int32[], Int32>( new Int32[] { 4, 23, 8174, 42, -1 }, 41 ),
                new KeyValuePair<Int32[], Int32>( new Int32[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3 }, 3 ),
                new KeyValuePair<Int32[], Int32>( new Int32[] { 2, 1, 1, 1, 53, 2 }, 4 ),
                new KeyValuePair<Int32[], Int32>( new Int32[] { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, 4 ),
                new KeyValuePair<Int32[], Int32>( new Int32[] { 3 }, 3 ),
                new KeyValuePair<Int32[], Int32>( new Int32[] {  }, -43 ),
            };

        foreach( var testCase in testCases ) {
            Console.WriteLine( $" Input: {testCase.Value}; {{ {String.Join(", ", testCase.Key)} }}\nOutput: {f( testCase.Key, testCase.Value )}\n" );
        }

         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

---

#### Releases

- **v1.1** -  `-1 byte`  - Thanks to [TheLethalCoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/296698?noredirect=1) suggestion.
- **v1.0** - `103 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

#### Notes

- None

Comment: `(int[] l,int r)=>` can just be `(l,r)=>`, however, you can also use currying to shave another byte off of that `l=>r=>`. Pass in a list instead of an array to save another byte by using `Count` instead of `Length`. You can set `y` = to zero and do a post increment in the array indexer instead.

Comment: Put that together for 90 bytes: `l=>r=>{for(int x=l.Count,y;--x>=0;)for(y=0;y<x;)if(l[x]+l[y++]==r)return 1>0;return 0>1;};`. Note that I haven't tested this put it looks correct. Now comes in at the same count as my Linq answer :)

Comment: Hey @TheLethalCoder, thanks for your suggestions, but some days ago I've got in a discussion with another member of CodeGolf and I have submitted myself to explicitly type the input types since then, hence the `(int[] l,int r)`. Also, I refrain from using `List`s and other classes that require `using`s -- although when I use them, I type the full name, i.e. `System.Collections.Generic.List`.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly type them but your choice. You can still save one byte by changing `y=-1` to `y=0` and post incrementing in the indexer instead of the loop condition.

Comment: If I'm thinking correctly, your suggestion is to change `for( y =- 1; ++y < x; )` to `for( y = 0; y++ < x; )`, but that would cause `IndexOutOfRangeException` to be thrown, which, to be fixed, I had to change the for to `for( y = 0; y < x; y++ )`, which would result in the same byte count.

Comment: No change `for(y=-1;++y<x;)if(l[x]+l[y]==r)` to `for(y=0;y<x;)if(l[x]+l[y++]==r)`.

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 77 bytes

```
{for(s=i=0;++i<NF;)for(j=0;++j<NF;){if(i==j)continue
if($i+$j==$NF)s=1}$0=s}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#VY2xDoMwDER3vuKGDCCEhBPTVqJeGfmJqkjJAFIpE@Lb05DQitoefO/Osl@H6ZXPYqVuy9Le@64tduKidlGvdsitiCse0/i24/LMAlC2VE5E9V0xC22qlnkj7w0YDXDBqTIQNJITDKIEGdrgRlcGa1QBMu3JbxvsE5P6QI0Ja7g7YOqkE/vdnH5X/I@yDw)

I could save 2 bytes by removing the `i=` in the `for(s=i=0...)`, but then it would only work for one line of data.  Since this isn't the shortest answer, I thought I'd make a general solution :)

Input is whitespace separated numbers with the last value being the desired sum.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 13 bytes

```
p
cd!i
i 2
 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jellyfish#@1/AlZyimMmVqWDEpWD4/3@0iYKRsYKFobmJgomRgq5hLJeJIQA)

### How it works

```
print(exists(i,from_base(1,permutations(i,2)))
```

where `i` are the inputs.